# Linear Quadratic Regulator Matrices Positivity

Tags: optimal-control

Shortly, the LQR problem says that: for $\begin{cases} x'=Ax+Bu \\ x(t_0)=x_0\end{cases}$ find:

$$\min_{u\in L^2(t_0,T; \mathbb{R}^m)} J(u)=\frac{1}{2}\left\{\int_{t_0}^T x^TQx+u^TRu+2x^TNu\ dt + x(T)^TPx(T)\right\}$$

where $Q,P$ are positive semi-definite matrices and $R$ is positive definite.

I know that there is an entire theory of finding the optimal control $u^*$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear%E2%80%93quadratic_regulator or http://www.joinville.udesc.br/portal/professores/marianasantos/materiais/lqrnotes_Regra_de_Bryson.pdf)

Why is so important that the matrices $Q,P,R$ be positive definite like I mentioned before? I know that there is a scalar product induced by this type of matrices, but is this so important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem

$$
\begin{aligned}
\min J &= \int_{t_0}^{t_f} x^TQx + u^TRu \; dt + \left[ x^TPx \right|_{t_f}\\
\text{Subject to:} \; x' &= Ax + Bu
\end{aligned}
$$

for $Q \geq 0$, $R > 0$, and $P \geq 0$, then you have

$$
0 \leq J \leq \infty
$$

Requiring $Q$ and $R$ to be positive (semi)definite prevents the integral from becoming unbounded on the lower end. Requiring $P$ to be positive semidefinite is the same idea, just not under the integral. Minimizing a function whose lower bound is $-\infty$ causes difficulties, if not impossible. Take this idea and extend it with the extra $x^TNu$ term, which is a bit more complicated since, in general, setting $N > 0$ will not prevent a lower unbounded integral.

Comment: When adding the $2\,x^\top N\,u$ term would also enable you to write the expression inside the integral as
$$
\begin{bmatrix}x\\u\end{bmatrix}^\top M\begin{bmatrix}x\\u\end{bmatrix},
$$
with
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}Q&N\\N^\top&R\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can now replace $Q\geq0$ with $M\geq0$. By now applying Schur's complement this can also be written as $Q-N\,R\,N^\top\geq0$.